# simplify rational function given pieces

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In a computer graphics context I need to compute a function that I could only define on regions. The function takes two variables $x_1,x_2$ both $\ge 0$, and has the form
$$
f(x_1,x_2) = \begin{cases}
     1+\frac{(x_2-1)^2}{x_2(x_1-x_2)}& \text{if } x_1<1, x_2>1 \\ 
     1+\frac{(x_1-1)^2}{x_1(x_2-x_1)}& \text{if } x_2<1, x_1>1 \\ 
\frac{1}{x_1x_2}&\text{if }x_1>1,x_2>1\\
1&\text{if }x_1<1,x_2<1
\end{cases}
$$
I'm trying to see if this can be phrased as a single hopefully rational function-looking that reduces to the cases on the 4 given regions. The function is continuous at the boundaries but I think not smooth, so I tried a few things using absolute values, but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define
$$\sigma_i := \text{sign}(x_i-1) = \frac{x_i-1}{|x_i-1|}, \quad x_i\neq 1$$
In general, given
$$f(x_1,x_2) = \begin{cases}
K_{++} & \text{if}\;\sigma_1=+1, \sigma_2=+1 \\
K_{+-} & \text{if}\;\sigma_1=+1, \sigma_2=-1 \\
K_{-+} & \text{if}\;\sigma_1=-1, \sigma_2=+1 \\
K_{--} & \text{if}\;\sigma_1=-1, \sigma_2=-1 
\end{cases}$$
we can write
$$
f(x_1,x_2) = \frac14\left(\begin{array}{ll}
\phantom{\;+\;}(1+\sigma_1)(1+\sigma_2)K_{++} 
\;+\; (1+\sigma_1)(1-\sigma_2)K_{+-} \\[1pt]
\;+\; (1-\sigma_1)(1+\sigma_2)K_{-+} 
\;+\; (1-\sigma_1)(1-\sigma_2)K_{--}\end{array}\right)
$$
so that, for a given pair of $\sigma_i$, only the desired term survives. For the function in question, we substitute
$$
K_{-+} = 1+\frac{(x_2-1)^2}{x_2(x_1-x_2)} \qquad 
K_{+-} = 1+\frac{(x_1-1)^2}{x_1(x_2-x_1)} \qquad 
K_{++} = \frac{1}{x_1x_2} \qquad
K_{--} = 1
$$
Expanding conveniently causes the $\sigma_1\sigma_2$ terms to vanish, leaving
$$f(x_1,x_2) = \frac{(x_1 - x_2) (1 + x_1 x_2) - \sigma_1 x_2(x_1-1)^2 + \sigma_2 x_1 (x_2-1)^2}{2 x_1 x_2 (x_1 - x_2)}$$
Finally, we might as well replace the $\sigma_i$s with their definitions:
$$f(x_1,x_2)=\frac12\left(1+\frac{1}{x_1x_2} -\frac{1}{x_1(x_1-x_2)}\frac{(x_1-1)^3}{|x_1-1|\phantom{^3}}+ \frac{1}{x_2 (x_1 - x_2)}\frac{(x_2-1)^3}{|x_2-1|\phantom{^3}}\right)$$
Done!